# "I have no room / I have no space" Which one sounds better?

Tags: word-choice

> I have no room in my house

or

> I have no space in my house

Which sounds better?

Answer (score 1):

To my (American) ear, "room"'s connotations are slightly more 2-dimensional, and "space"'s connotations are slightly more 3-dimensional.

Thus, if you have so much clutter that you don't have "elbow room", or cannot find any more floor area for activities, "You have no room in your house."

If you have so much clutter that you cannot find a place (even up high, or down low, or in a closet or cabinet) to put anything, "You have no space in your house."

It is easy to imagine someone who has unused space in their house, who does not have any more room for new activities (or for people to move in).  It requires a dedicated "hoarder" to use up all of the space in a house.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same in almost every context, but I'd have a slight preference for the second if it was in response to someone asking if they could stay in your house for a while. The reason I'd prefer the second is because in the first, "room" could become ambiguous. It could mean the same as "space", but it could also be taken to be a lazily stated reference to "a room".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an empty area available to be used, you can use either room or space, without any difference in meaning. So both sentences sound equally correct; however, the word space is more clear.

I think every house  has at least one room, so the first sentence doesn't convey any sense but an empty area.